# I want install Windows 7 on my Macbook after I formated Snow Leopard

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I want install Windows 7 on my Macbook Pro after I formatted Snow Leopard.
The Macbook is now empty with no OS on it.

How can I install Windows 7 on my MBP that has a formatted hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

You need to boot from the OS X install DVD which was bundled with your Mac (start the Mac with pressed C while the DVD is inserted). Launch "Disk Utility via "Utility" in the menu bar and create a partition which is "MS DOS FAT" formatted. If its done replace the DVD with the Windows install DVD and boot again with pressed C button. After the Windows install assistant has started, reformat the partition to NTFS and continue installing Windows.

Be aware that Windows OEM versions won't work. It must be a retail version.

Comment: what if i don't have OS X install DVD ?

Answer (score -1):

You have to format your drive and partition to NTFS.

The challenge is, of course, that in order to format, you need to be able to boot the computer. You make reference to the computer once running Snow Leopard. If you have the Snow Leopard install disc, you can boot from that, then run Disk Utility and use it to format the hard drive to get it ready for Windows.

Select a primary drive to install window.

Comment: And how exactly can the OP format his drive?